Compare against null (0000-00-00 00:00:00) datetime with Laravel Eloquent
Is there an elegant way to do compare against undefined datetime in Laravel Eloquent ORM?
Person::where('died_at', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')

This does not work, as expected:
Person::whereNull('died_at')

Laravel version is 7.

Can you please share what is expected here, whereNull will return true for undefined.
Correct syntax will be Person::whereNull('died_at')->get();

Try this Person::where('died_at', '!=', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')

My tip would be, if it isn't too late, to disallow '0000-00-00 00:00:00' dates entirely in the first place. They add a lot of ridiculous complication to date handling, and they don't provide any actual benefit. The only reason why they typically exist is because legacy MySQL settings would allow them and many programmers don't notice or care.

This may indicate a problem with your data. Zero dates used to be allowed in MySQL (and probably still are behind some sort of flag) but overall it is not recommended to do so. What is likely happening is you did (or still do) have that flag enabled so what you have there are not actual null dates but zero dates which are different. I suggest you manually replace all those zero dates with null and then switch that flag off so you don't end up in the same situation again

@ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks, this is the answer I was looking for, did not know that.

'0000-00-00 00:00:00' is not null its a string that's why u are not getting data
best way to create died_at column as nullable
$table->datetime('dead_at')->nullable();
then u can try

Person::whereNull('died_at')

